# Mutate using R "%>% could not be found"

Tags: r, dplyr

I am running Rstudio on my macbook Pro for a coursera course "learning to program with R"

I cant seem to figure out why the "mutate" function isnt working.

I am using the following code.

```
{r calc-total-bapt-vars-save}
arbuthnot <- arbuthnot %>%
  mutate(total = boys + girls)
```

I keep getting an error that "%>% could not be found. Am I missing something?

Comment: You need to include R library `magrittr` if you want to use the pipe operator. So just include `library(magrittr)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
install.packages("magrittr") 
install.packages("dplyr")

library("dplyr") 
library("magrittr")
```

`mutate` belongs to the `dplyr` library, while `%>%` (pipe) belongs to `magrittr`.

Comment: Part of the packages they asked us to install were the "dplyr"

Comment: But are you using it in your session?

Comment: Whenever I need to use a package do I have to use the "library" function to do so?

Comment: Only the first time you need to use it in your session.

Comment: If you're editing in the console, you only need to do it at the beginning of your session, but if you want to save a persistent script, you might want to put it at the top of your file.

Comment: got it. **insert thumbs up***  I understand. Is there a place to find what packages include what commands?

Comment: `https://www.rdocumentation.org/`, you can probably search by command/function and or package

Comment: Thanks Man. yea I use this for things as well.

Comment: FWIW the pipe, `%>%` is imported by `dplyr`. Loading `dplyr` will provide access to the pipe as well as `mutate`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`install.packages("magrittr")`

`require(magrittr)`

The pipe operator `%>%` is a magrittr functionality

Comment: Thanks when I added this then it gave me an error about not being able to find "mutate"

Comment: You will have to call the package dplyr too 

`install.packages("dplyr")`


`library(dplyr)`